# Sharepoint c# retrieve all site and subsite

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'am trying to retrieve all site and subsite in sharepoint but i get access denied.

I read about to use GetSubwebsForCurrentUser() property, but i get the same message.

My code is the next

```
            foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
            {                    
                foreach (SPSite siteCollection in webApp.Sites)
                {
                    foreach(SPWeb web in siteCollection.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
                    {
                       dropDownSite.Items.Add(web.Url);
                    }


                }
            }
```

please i need help! Thanks!

Comment: Where is this code running from? Web part? Timer job? Something else?

Comment: Just a heads up, there is now a [SharePoint stack exchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). Its in beta but you should post over there (or moderator could move this question there). It will help the site to get more traction :)

Comment: Are you looking for user contextual based site lists? If so are you doing this just to populate a list of dropdowns? If so i'd suggest the portalsitemapprovider. Also your code will leave every one of those webs in an undisposed state resulting in a huge memory leak every time this runs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will probably need to call `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate())`

You could do an inline delegate if you wish, something like:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
    {                    
        foreach (SPSite siteCollection in webApp.Sites)
        {
            foreach(SPWeb web in siteCollection.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
            {
                 dropDownSite.Items.Add(web.Url);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, is this code running on the server that is hosting the Sharepoint portal?  What version of Sharepoint are you running?

Also, would it make sense to use the Webservices that Sharepoint exposes?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979690(v=office.12).aspx

If you are running this code on the same server as SP, then make sure that your credentials have access to SP.  If you are calling this from a website, also make sure that you are not running as "Anonymous".

Over all, I think taking advantage of the webservices is the easiest way to get it working.  But make sure that you have the right permissions being sent and that that user has access (in the SP configurations) to that data.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use SPSite.AllWebs Access Denied message appears!
This statement is only correct as long as the current user is a site collection administrator

So for all users this function get all site and sub sites.

```
    public static IEnumerable<SPWeb> DescendantSites(this SPWeb input)
    {
        foreach (SPWeb web in input.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
        {
            yield return web;
            foreach (var subnode in web.DescendantSites())
                yield return subnode;
        }
    }
```